# SVG String to UIImage for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, svg, uiimageview, uiimage

I try to make an iOS application and use Github API with SDWebImage. Here is the code to get "User Profile Image".

```
[manager GET:@"https://api.github.com/users/(here is your account name)/following?page=1&per_page=100"
  parameters:nil
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

         NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject
                                                          options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                                            error:nil];
         for (NSDictionary *dic in array) {
             [profileImageArray addObject:[dic valueForKey:@"avatar_url"]];
         }

     }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
     }];
```

this works well.

However, when I try to get Contribution heatmap images, I can't get images of Contribution heatmaps, because contribution heat maps are "SVG String".

Contribution heatmap is Here.

https://qiita-image-store.s3.amazonaws.com/0/19462/43207385-f3e4-1c96-b288-78802beee357.png

Then, after researching, I tried "SVGKit", "PocketSVG", "SKUBezierPath+SVG", and so on. But such libraries not works well for SVG "String" but SVG "files".

I can get a contribution heatmap SVG by using this URL

```
https://github.com/users/(here is username)/contributions
```

Here is that result.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihzWt.png

I can't treat this response as UIImage. I also tried to change responseData to NSData and convert UIImage, but it also doesn't work well.

**Could you teach me how to treat "github contribution heatmap's SVG" as UIImage?**

Answer (score 3):

[SVGgh](https://github.com/GenerallyHelpfulSoftware/SVGgh) contains an SVGRenderer class which has an init method—initWithString:(NSString*)anSVG—you can use a renderer created that way to tell an SVGDocumentView to render your SVG. I wrote SVGgh.

The SVGRenderer class now has a `-(UIImage*)asImageWithSize:(CGSize)maximumSize andScale:(CGFloat)scale` method which will directly create a UIImage.

In your case, it doesn't appear that you are getting a complete SVG document as it's missing its XML declaration. So you should probably take the  block and add it to a basic XML prefix such as in Swift:

```
let xmlPrefix  = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN\"
\"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd\">"

let documentString = xmlPrefix + serverImage

let renderer = SVGRenderer(string: documentString)
let image = renderer.asImageWithSize(CGSize(100, 100)), andScale:2.0)
```

Notice that I used the \ character to escape all the quotation hash marks. I have not compiled this snippet so the Swift might be a bit off.

Comment: Hi, what is the format of the string needed, I am trying to use your library. an example will be great. Thanks

Comment: The format is an SVG document. So you want to take the string you get from your server and take the part that is inside <svg></svg> blocks and give it an XML header. I'll edit my response a bit.

Comment: This is what I did but I get a black rectangle instead of the image (Testing on a browser works fine). I there a way I can present my code in  a note ? Thanks

Comment: OK I added a new question with my sample code and SVG string. It would be great if you could take a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36014725/creating-a-uiimage-from-svg-string