# Creating a UIImage from SVG string

Tags: ios, svg, uiimage

Hi I am trying to present an SVG image from data that I get from the server.

I am using this code with a library called  [SVGgh](https://github.com/GenerallyHelpfulSoftware/SVGgh)-

```
NSData *svgData =  [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:svgStr options:0];
NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:svgData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSString  *finalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN\"\"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd\">%@", newStr];
aRenderer = [[SVGRenderer alloc] initWithString:finalString];
UIImage *image = [aRenderer asImageWithSize:CGSizeMake(200, 200) andScale:1.0];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200.0, 200.0);
imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

But all I get is a black view.
Can someone direct me to what is going wrong ?

Here is the string I pass -
 Here is the data after :

```
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 259.6 312.79"><defs><style>.a,.e{font-size:18px;}.a,.c,.e,.f{font-family:Iowan Old Style;}.a,.c{font-style:italic;}.b,.d{fill:none;}.c{font-size:23px;}.d{stroke:#000;}.f{font-size:16px;}</style></defs><title>ACT-Math-7862-q</title><text class="a" transform="translate(70.83 217.15)">H</text><rect class="b" x="-435.5" y="-153.52" width="1024" height="768"/><text class="c" transform="translate(222.5 266.48)">x</text><rect class="b" x="222.15" y="241.56" width="9.06" height="25"/><polyline class="d" points="1 255.5 209.82 255.5 210.82 255.5"/><polygon points="209.82 260.3 219.42 255.5 209.82 250.7 209.82 260.3"/><rect class="b" y="249.7" width="220.42" height="11.6"/><text class="c" transform="translate(33.5 24.48)">y</text><rect class="b" x="25.85" width="25.74" height="30"/><polyline class="d" points="38.2 286.16 38.2 43.42 38.2 42.42"/><polygon points="43 43.42 38.2 33.82 33.4 43.42 43 43.42"/><rect class="b" x="-435.5" y="-153.52" width="1024" height="768"/><rect class="b" x="32.4" y="32.82" width="11.6" height="254.33"/><text class="e" transform="translate(190.5 216.48)">(8,2)</text><text class="e" transform="translate(62.5 106.48)">(1,5)</text><text class="a" transform="translate(52.5 106.48)">J</text><polygon class="d" points="214.68 116.69 181.75 199.81 92.68 199.72 62.12 116.39 214.68 116.69"/><text class="e" transform="translate(86.16 217.15)">(4,2)</text><text class="e" transform="translate(219.5 106.48)">(9,5)</text><text class="a" transform="translate(179.88 217.15)">L</text><text class="a" transform="translate(206.5 106.48)">K</text><rect class="b" x="-435.5" y="-153.52" width="1024" height="768"/><circle cx="214.68" cy="116.69" r="1.87"/><circle cx="62.12" cy="116.4" r="1.87"/><circle cx="92.68" cy="199.72" r="1.87"/><circle cx="181.75" cy="199.82" r="1.87"/><text class="f" transform="translate(22.5 305.48)">Note: <tspan x="44.2" y="0">F</tspan><tspan x="53.27" y="0">igure not drawn to scale.</tspan></text></svg>
```

Thanks
Shani

Comment: You should probably put in a feature request on the SVGgh git repository. Looking at the SVG you are trying to use, it's an unusual SVG/CSS hybrid which makes use of CSS classes to declare styles. The SVGgh library does not know what to do with class declarations, and renders the black rectangle you are seeing.

Comment: Or maybe you should try another library to see if they can handle classes. Probably you'll have to save out a temporary file with the XML header and load it from disk.